# How we can get under development dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

I encounter an issue that, I have 3 projects porject_1,porject_2 and porject_3.

porject_1 contains one abstract class for example ClassDef.java, and porject_2 and porject_3 are implementing ClassDef.java in there code some where. 
 If ClassDef.java has added some new API in  porject_1(under development means not released yet  ) which should be verified by porject_2 & porject_3.
But in maven  porject_2 & porject_3 need  porject_1 dependency to get new implementation and we can not add porject_1 development jar into class path of porject_2 & porject_3 project in maven hence I can't take latest change in both dependent project at same time. how could I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not a Maven expert but it seems that project 2 & 3 are dependent on project 1 so in the maven file those projects should have some kind of dependency on project 1.  Sort of like "project1-is-over-there" so that 2 & 3 can find project 1's jar;

Comment: ssimm thanks for comment , yes we can specify from were project 2&3 would get project_1.jar but this case is  like project_1 code changes are not committed yet because those code changes are not verified from both dependent project_2&3 previously we can get dev jar through ant and use in project_2&3 and verified but how would we do in case of maven how can we get intermediate dev dependency  ?

Comment: All projects will have to agree on how to use the new API, i.e. what are it's methods/classes.  Until you get that no one can do any coding for this new API.  You do not to agree on how exactly it will be done inside the classes/methods, that can be worked out later.  Look at it from a javadoc point of view.  If you can write the necessary Javadoc documentation for the API in project 1 then you have enough agreement.  If not, lock everyone in the room again.  Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a multi module build which means all three projects are under the same folder structure and define dependencies between each other. Means also having a single git repository or located under trunk in SVN ...than you simply develop there....

Comment: It's not multi module project they all are on different SVN location.l